# Tensorflow dataset API with ListDirectory

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use the Tensorflow Dataset API to create one batch per folder (each folder containing images). I have the following simple code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import pdb

def parse_file(filename):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [48, 48])
    return image_resized #, label

def parse_dir(frame_dir):
    filenames = tf.gfile.ListDirectory(frame_dir)
    batch = tf.constant(5)
    batch = tf.map_fn(parse_file, filenames)
    return batch

directory = "../Detections/NAC20171125"
# filenames = tf.constant([os.path.join(directory, f) for f in os.listdir(directory)])
frames = [os.path.join(directory, str(f)) for f in range(10)]


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((frames))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_dir)

dataset = dataset.batch(256)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            batch = sess.run(next_element)
            print(batch.shape)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

However, tf.gfile.ListDirectory (in parse_dir) expects a normal string instead of a Tensor. So now the error is

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'arg0:0' shape=() dtype=string>
```

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that [`tf.gfile.ListDirectory()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gfile/ListDirectory) is a Python function that expects a Python string, and the `frame_dir` argument to `parse_dir()` is a `tf.Tensor`. Therefore you require an equivalent TensorFlow operation to list the files in the directory, and [`tf.data.Dataset.list_files()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files) (based on [`tf.matching_files()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matching_files)) is probably the closest equivalent.

```
directory = "../Detections/NAC20171125"
frames = [os.path.join(directory, str(f)) for f in range(10)]

# Start with a dataset of directory names.
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(frames)

# Maps each subdirectory to the list of files in that subdirectory and flattens
# the result.
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda dir: tf.data.Dataset.list_files(dir + "/*"))

# Maps each filename to the parsed and resized image data.
dataset = dataset.map(parse_file)

dataset = dataset.batch(256)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```